# Filtering nested relationship table Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have Project and Reservations table relationship trying to filter the `reservations` by the dates inside the project. But getting the error of

> mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

the nested relation is look like below/

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "reservations": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "project_id": 1,
            "date": "2020-01-13",
        }
    ]
}
```

The below code isn't working:

```
$startDate =  $request->get("startDate");
$endDate =  $request->get("endDate");

return Project::find($id)->with(["reservations", function($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
     $query->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
}])->get();
```

**project** model

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'projects';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public $with = ["reservations"];

    public function reservations() {
        return $this->hasMany(Reservation::class);
    }
    
}
```

and **reservations** model

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "reservations";
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function project() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, "project_id", "id");
    }

}
```

Comment: what $startDate and end date format

Comment: request url is `api/projects/1?startDate=2020-01-13&endDate=2021-02-15`

Comment: so date format in db also same right

Comment: yep it's same... "date" column setted as a dateField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in your query.Since you call `find()` first then calling `with`.Also while using array in `with` you must use `=>` for callback So it should be like below

```
$startDate =  $request->get("startDate");
$endDate =  $request->get("endDate");

return Project::with(["reservations"=>function($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
     $query->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
}])->find($id);
```

Also you can use without array in with method like below

```
Project::with("reservations",function($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
     $query->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
})->find($id);
```

Comment: still having the same error: `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: can you show model of  Project and resevations code

Comment: i have updated my answer.please copy that

Comment: I updated the question with models, please check it out.

Comment: it worked with the arrow... I am a little bit suprised, because I don't understand why.

Comment: yes i forgot to point while adding.i will update

Comment: The arrow is required when filtering a relationship on a `with`